# No vertical scroll bar for the code snippets on Google Chrome on iPad

Tags: bug, google-chrome, code, ipad

There seems to be no vertical scroll bar for the code snippets on Google Chrome on iPad, e.g.:

[Unit test best-practices in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39092/10721):

[image]

Comment: That's... not something we have any control over. A lot of mobile applications hide scrollbars when it's not being actively used. Google Chrome does the same thing on Android devices. The scrollbar is only shown while it's being scrolled.

Comment: @animuson thanks, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: That screenshot is of Safari, not Google Chrome? (Although it's the same principle, since Google Chrome uses Safari's WebKit on iOS) @animuson CSS *can* be used to control this by overriding `::-webkit-scrollbar`, not that I think it's necessary.

Comment: @grgarside Good catch, it was Safari. Some issue on Google Chrome though as you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

iOS (and macOS by default if a trackpad is in use) hide scrollbars when you are not scrolling an area. The scrollbar will be shown briefly when a scrollable view appears, then the bar will fade. For subregions which scroll, depending on the CSS, the scrollbar may not appear at all. SE **do** have control over this through CSS if they desire, by overriding the `::-webkit-scrollbar`, but I don't think that's necessary.